# assign instruction to thread

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, multicore, openmp, llvm

i need split a sequential program to multithread. the first step I am going to assign each basic block of program to a thread, so i want create a function for each basic block and add instruction of basic block into it and assign every function to a thread. for this purpose i want to write llvm-pass.
how could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

http://liberty.princeton.edu/videos/step-by-step.php

Look at the above link and read the related papers. It can't be implemented a couple of weeks. You may need to do a lot of background study. Of course, LLVM is a very good framework to test you automatic parallelization ideas.